# Issue with TFS populating properly in MS Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, ms-project

I have a field defined in TFS so that it maps to the Finish date in MS Project. When I load the data from TFS into MS Project that field does not populate into the Finish field. However, when I populate the Finish field in MS Project and click on Publish it DOES update the field in TFS with the added/changed date.

What am I doing wrong? I mapped my ETA field to the Finished field, but when updated it only goes from Project to TFS. When I add an ETA date to something in TFS it will not populate in Project when I try to open the work item from TFS to Project.

Let me know if that doesn't make sense or if you need further clarification. 
Thank you, 
Shanna

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is expected if the full field name you use is not the one from Microsoft.
To be clearer, if you created the field yourself with a full name you came up with: it won't be used by MS Project.

You have to just the Microsoft's field, in this case: Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.FinishDate for MS Project to pull the data from the Work Items when loading the MS Project sheet.

Note that you can set the relationship from WIT Field and MS Project field manually in the Team Project definition. Use the Process Template Editor (from the TFS Power tools) to do so.

More info about the Scheduling fields [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461579.aspx)